# Applying theme in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.1 in my project. I'm facing a problem in applying a theme. I added the dark-hive-1.0.3.jar to the project and configured in `web.xml` as following.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>dark-hive</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When I run the project, following exception arises.

> javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-dark-hive" library

How is this problem caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: In the future questions please do not be rude by stating "Urgent help plz". You are not more important than anyone else asking a question here. Just ask the question the smart way. Otherwise you would run into receiving downvotes and be ignored.

Comment: I got sir. BTW, I think I had written 'plz'. I didn't know, how it caused rudeness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It needs to be placed in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp. If you're using an IDE, do not fiddle with "build path" properties of the project. Just dropping the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder will trigger all the IDE magic to do the necessary tasks.